# listView not receving data?

Tags: c#, winforms, sockets, listview, asynchronous

So on line: 225 I manage to to display the hostname to an textbox, but when i want to add it to the listview on line: 226 it does not work for some reason, the ip gets added and its port, but not the hostname.

Here is a github if you want to check it out yourself will all the files and the windows, you can test connecting to the server with telnet if you dont know anything about networking with this command in command prompt, you might need to enable telnet too: telnet 127.0.0.1 1234

dont use the max port is set as by default wont work.

Github: https://github.com/cda4/Anhk-Controller

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;

namespace AnhkController
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Server _server;

        public bool serverOnline = false;


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            listView1.Columns.Add("IP Address", 120);  // Add another column to ListView control in the Form class
            listView1.Columns.Add("Hostname", 120);   // Added Hostname column

            _server = new Server(this.ConsoleTextBox, this.ClientsLabel, listView1, IpAddressTextBox.Text, int.Parse(PortTextBox.Text));  // Pass a reference to TextBox and Label controls and ListView control in the constructor
        }

        public void EndScroll()
        {



            ConsoleTextBox.SelectionStart = ConsoleTextBox.Text.Length;
            ConsoleTextBox.ScrollToCaret();
        }

        private async void StartServerButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (serverOnline == false)
            {
                _server = new Server(this.ConsoleTextBox, this.ClientsLabel, listView1, IpAddressTextBox.Text, int.Parse(PortTextBox.Text));
                serverOnline = true;
                StartServerButton.Text = "Stop Server";
                ServerStatusIndicatorLabal.ForeColor = Color.Green;
                ServerStatusIndicatorLabal.Text = "Online";
                ConsoleTextBox.Text += Environment.NewLine + "Listening for connections..." + Environment.NewLine; // Log message on the form\n
                EndScroll();
                await Task.Run(() => _server.StartServer());
            }
            else
            {
                serverOnline = false;
                StartServerButton.Text = "Start Server";
                ServerStatusIndicatorLabal.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                ServerStatusIndicatorLabal.Text = "Offline";
                ConsoleTextBox.Text += Environment.NewLine + "Server shutdown successfully..." + Environment.NewLine; // Log message on the form\n
                EndScroll();
            }
        }

        private void listView1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
            {
                var item = this.listView1.GetItemAt(e.X, e.Y); // Get the selected ListViewItem

                if (item != null)
                {
                    ContextMenuStrip.Show((Control)sender, new Point(e.X, e.Y));  // Show the context menu at the cursor's position
                }
            }
        }

        public async Task SendAsync(Socket clientSocket, byte[] buffer, SocketFlags socketflags)
        {
            await clientSocket.SendAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), socketflags);
        }

        private async Task<int> ReceiveData(Socket handler, byte[] buffer)
        {
            return await handler.ReceiveAsync(buffer, SocketFlags.None);
        }

        private void SendDataToClient(Server.ClientListViewItem client, string message)
        {
            byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message); // Convert your message into bytes array

            try
            {
                this.SendAsync(client.Socket, buffer, SocketFlags.None).Wait();  // Send data asynchronously to the client's socket

                ReceiveSystemInfoFromClient(client); // Call new method for receiving system info from client
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }

        public async Task ReceiveSystemInfoFromClient(Server.ClientListViewItem client)  // This new method will receive system info from a specific client and print it in the TextBox
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

            int receivedBytes = await this.ReceiveData(client.Socket, buffer);  // Receive data asynchronously from the client's socket

            string systemInfo = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, receivedBytes); // Convert received bytes to a string

            ConsoleTextBox.Text += Environment.NewLine + $"{systemInfo}" + Environment.NewLine; // Log message on the form\n
            EndScroll();
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // If there's any selected text, just select it. Otherwise, select all
            if (ConsoleTextBox.SelectionLength == 0)
                ConsoleTextBox.SelectAll();

            // Scroll to the end of the TextBox
            ConsoleTextBox.ScrollToCaret();
        }
        // System Tab
        private void sysToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Get selected ListViewItem and cast it to Server.ClientListViewItem type
            var client = (Server.ClientListViewItem)listView1.SelectedItems[0];

            if (client != null)
            {
                ConsoleTextBox.Text += Environment.NewLine + "Sending System Information Request...";
                SendDataToClient(client, "systeminfo"); // Call your method for sending data to the client
            }
        }

        private void shellToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Get selected ListViewItem and cast it to Server.ClientListViewItem type
            var client = (Server.ClientListViewItem)listView1.SelectedItems[0];

            if (client != null)
            {
                ConsoleTextBox.Text += Environment.NewLine + "Shell Active..." + Environment.NewLine;
                EndScroll();
                SendDataToClient(client, "systemshell"); // Call your method for sending data to the client
            }
        }

        private void shutdownToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Get selected ListViewItem and cast it to Server.ClientListViewItem type
            var client = (Server.ClientListViewItem)listView1.SelectedItems[0];

            if (client != null)
            {
                ConsoleTextBox.Text += Environment.NewLine + "Sending Shutdown Request..." + Environment.NewLine;
                EndScroll();
                SendDataToClient(client, "shutdown"); // Call your method for sending data to the client
            }
        }

        private void IpAddressTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (serverOnline)
            {
                // Stop current server
                serverOnline = false;
                StartServerButton.Text = "Start Server";
                ServerStatusIndicatorLabal.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                ServerStatusIndicatorLabal.Text = "Offline";

                // Update _server instance with new IP address and start server again
                _server = new Server(this.ConsoleTextBox, this.ClientsLabel, listView1, IpAddressTextBox.Text, int.Parse(PortTextBox.Text));
                serverOnline = true;
                StartServerButton_Click(null, null); // Start the server again
            }
        }

        private void PortTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (serverOnline)
            {
                // Stop current server
                serverOnline = false;
                StartServerButton.Text = "Start Server";
                ServerStatusIndicatorLabal.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                ServerStatusIndicatorLabal.Text = "Offline";

                // Update _server instance with new port and start server again
                _server = new Server(this.ConsoleTextBox, this.ClientsLabel, listView1, IpAddressTextBox.Text, int.Parse(PortTextBox.Text));
                serverOnline = true;
                StartServerButton_Click(null, null); // Start the server again
            }
        }

    }

    public class Server : Form
    {
        private readonly Socket _serverSocket;
        public delegate void UpdateTextCallback(string text);
        private readonly Control _textbox, _label; // Add a field for TextBox control in the Server class
        public int clients { get; set; } = 0;  // Added "public" here to allow access from Form1 class.
        private System.Windows.Forms.ListView listView;   // Added ListView control to store connected clients
        private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox ConsoleTextBox;
        private Label ClientsLabel;

        public Server(Control textbox, Control label, System.Windows.Forms.ListView lv, string ipAddress, int port)
     : base()  // Call the base constructor
        {
            IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ipAddress), port);
            _serverSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            _serverSocket.Bind(ipEndPoint);
            _serverSocket.Listen(500); // Set the backlog size to 500 connections
            listView = lv;
            _textbox = textbox;
            _label = label;
        }

        public async Task StartServer()
        {
            UpdateTextOnForm("Server started on " + _serverSocket.LocalEndPoint + Environment.NewLine); // Log message on the form with IP address and port number

            while (true)
            {
                Socket clientSocket = await AcceptClient();  // <-- This is now correct.

                string ip = ((IPEndPoint)clientSocket.RemoteEndPoint).Address.ToString();
                string hostname = Dns.GetHostEntry(ip).HostName;
                UpdateTextOnForm("Client connected: " + clientSocket.RemoteEndPoint + ", Hostname: " + hostname + Environment.NewLine);

                clients++;
                listView.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => listView.Items.Add(new ClientListViewItem(clientSocket.RemoteEndPoint.ToString(), clientSocket, hostname))));  // Add new ListView item with IP address and Socket
                UpdateLabel();

                _ = Task.Run(() => HandleClient(clientSocket));
            }
        }

        private void RemoveDisconnectedClientFromListView(string address)
        {
            listView.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() =>
            {
                foreach (ListViewItem item in listView.Items)
                {
                    if ((item as ClientListViewItem)?.Socket?.RemoteEndPoint?.ToString() == address)   // Check the IP address of each connected client
                        listView.Items.Remove(item);
                }
            }));
        }

        private async Task<int> ReceiveData(Socket handler, byte[] buffer)
        {
            return await handler.ReceiveAsync(buffer, SocketFlags.None);
        }

        public async Task HandleClient(Socket clientSocket)
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    int receivedBytes = await ReceiveData(clientSocket, buffer);

                    if (receivedBytes == 0) // Client has disconnected
                    {
                        UpdateTextOnForm("Client disconnected: " + clientSocket.RemoteEndPoint + Environment.NewLine);

                        clients--;
                        RemoveDisconnectedClientFromListView(clientSocket.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());
                        UpdateLabel();
                        return; // Exit this task when client disconnects
                    }

                    // Process received data...
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    UpdateTextOnForm("Client disconnected: " + clientSocket.RemoteEndPoint + Environment.NewLine);
                    Console.WriteLine($"An error occurred: {ex}");
                    clients--;
                    RemoveDisconnectedClientFromListView(clientSocket.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());
                    UpdateLabel();
                    return; // Exit this task when an error occurs
                }
            }
        }

        public class ClientListViewItem : ListViewItem // Custom ListViewItem that includes a Socket field
        {
            public Socket Socket { get; set; }
            public string Hostname { get; set; }  // Added property for the client's hostname

            public ClientListViewItem(string text, Socket socket, string hostname) : base(text)
            {
                this.Socket = socket;
                this.Hostname = hostname;     // Set the hostname property to the provided value
            }
        }


        private void UpdateTextOnForm(string text)  // Method to update TextBox's content on UI thread
        {
            _textbox.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => _textbox.Text += $"{text}\n"));
        }

        private void UpdateLabel()  // method to update label with current number of clients
        {
            _label.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => _label.Text = $"Clients: {clients}"));
        }

        private async Task<Socket> AcceptClient()
        {
            return await _serverSocket.AcceptAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Title might be a bit miss leading it does get data but only the ip and port.